# Splitting/reading CSV file by distinct row

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pyspark

I have a csv file with 3 columns.

```
Key,Branch,Account 
a,213,234567
a,454,457900
a,562,340094
a,200,456704
b,400,850988
b,590,344433
c,565,678635
c,300,453432
c,555,563546
c,001,660905
```

I would like to iterate through each row and get distinct rows from the Key column (a,b & c) and split them into 3 different pyspark datagrams.

```
   a,213,234567
   a,454,457900
   a,562,340094
   a,200,456704


   b,400,850988
   b,590,344433


   c,565,678635
   c,300,453432
   c,555,563546
   c,001,660905
```

Comment: is the output correct? There are 4 rows for a but output has 3 rows.

Comment: if you are trying to save the different dataframes as different files in a file system, look at my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048027/how-to-manage-physical-data-placement-of-a-dataframe-across-the-cluster-with-pys/60048672#60048672. python/pandas solutions are not for big data.

Comment: Alright, what’s the problem? Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
csv_string = """Key,Branch,Account 
a,213,234567
a,454,457900
a,562,340094
a,200,456704
b,400,850988
b,590,344433
c,565,678635
c,300,453432
c,555,563546
c,001,660905"""

import csv
import io

#
# 1. Parse csv_string into a list of ordereddicts
#

def parse_csv(string):
    # if you are reading from a file you don't need to do this
    # StringIO nonsense -- just pass the file to csv.DictReader()
    string_file = io.StringIO(string)
    reader = csv.DictReader(string_file)
    return list(reader)

csv_table = parse_csv(csv_string)

#
# 2. Loop through each line of the table and get the key
#  - If we have seen the key before, put the line in the list
#    with other lines that had the same key
#  - If not, start a new list for that key
#

result = {}

for line in csv_table:
    key = line["Key"].strip()
    print(key, ":", line)
    if key in result:
        result[key].append(line)
    else:
        result[key] = [line]

#
# 3. Finally, print the result.
# The lines will probably be easier to deal with if you keep them 
# in their parsed form, but for readability we can join the values
# of the line back into a string with commas
#

print(result)
print("")

for key_list in result.values():
    for line in key_list:
        print(",".join(line.values()))
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pandas** library to do the same and it will also provides you capability to do more operations with minimal code.
Please read about pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)

Here is the code to get desired output. I am storing data in dictionary so you can get desired data using `dict[key]` ex. `dict[a]`

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=",")

keys = df["Key"].unique() #This will provide all unique keys from csv

sorted_DF = df.groupby("Key") #Sort data based on value of column Key

dict = {} #To store data based on key
for key in keys:
    dict[key] = sorted_DF.get_group(key).values.tolist()

for key in keys:
    print("{} : {}".format(key, dict[key]))
```

**Output**:

a : [['a', 213, 234567], ['a', 454, 457900], ['a', 562, 340094], ['a', 200, 456704]]

b : [['b', 400, 850988], ['b', 590, 344433]]

c : [['c', 565, 678635], ['c', 300, 453432], ['c', 555, 563546], ['c', 1, 660905]]