# PysparkSQL dataframe - Split dataframe into multiple files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark sql functions from version 2.5.4. I have the following data in a pyspark.sql.dataframe:

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (302, 'foo'), # values
        (203, 'bar'),
        (202, 'foo'),
        (202, 'bar'),
        (172, 'xxx'),
        (172, 'yyy'),
    ],
    ['LU', 'input'] # column labels
)

display(df)
```

What I would like to do is create a separate csv file for each 'LU'. So the csv's would look like this:

**LU_302.csv**

```
 LU_302 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (302, 'foo'), # values
    ],
    ['LU', 'input'] # column labels
)
```

**LU_203.csv**

```
 LU_203 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (203, 'bar'), # values
    ],
    ['LU', 'input'] # column labels
)
```

**LU_202.csv**

```
 LU_202 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (202, 'foo'), # values
        (202, 'bar'), # values
    ],
    ['LU', 'input'] # column labels
)
```

**LU_172.csv**

```
 LU_202 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (172, 'xxx'), # values
        (172, 'yyy'), # values
    ],
    ['LU', 'input'] # column labels
)
```

My separated dataframes here are spark dataframes but I would like them to be in csv - this is just for illustration purposes.

So you can see the dataframe has been split into separate dataframes using the 'LU' variable. I've been looking into how to do this using a while loop that runs over the dataframe and prints a new csv to a file path but can't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048027/how-to-manage-physical-data-placement-of-a-dataframe-across-the-cluster-with-pys/60048672#60048672 that should help. u dont use loops in spark, you have to use inbuilt functions to do work in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the dataframe by using partition, like:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy('LU').format('csv').option('header','true').save(file-path)
```