# Modifying number of output files per write-partition with spark

Tags: pyspark

I have a data source that consists of a huge amount of small files. I would like to save this partitioned by column `user_id` to another storage:

```
sdf = spark.read.json("...")
sdf.write.partitionBy("user_id").json("...")
```

The reason for this is I want another system to be able to delete only select users' data upon request.

This works, but, I still get many files within each partition (due to my input data). For performance reasons I would like to reduce the number of files within each partition, ideally simply to one (the process will run each day, so having an output file per user per day would work well).

How do I obtain this with pyspark?

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048027/how-to-manage-physical-data-placement-of-a-dataframe-across-the-cluster-with-pys/60048672#60048672 could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **repartition** to ensure that each partition gets one file

```
sdf.repartition('user_id').write.partitionBy("user_id").json("...")
```

This will make sure for each partition one file is created but in case of coalesce if there are more than one partition it can cause trouble.

Comment: Read this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce

Answer (score 1):

Just add `coalesce` and no. of file you want.

```
sdf.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("user_id").json("...")
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that repartition (as proposed by Shubham Jain) was the fastest, so I accepted his/her answer.

Comment: coalesce will always be more efficient than reparition in the performance when there is a reduce in partition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce @casparjespersen

Comment: This was not my experience. I'll be happy to share more details about setup/data if you're interested.

Comment: Hey @QuickSilver please go through this link specially the 5th point https://datanoon.com/blog/spark_repartition_coalesce/  This explained the concept in very simple ways and I am open for further discussion also. Coalesce has some limitations hence should be used cautiously.

Comment: I have exactly the same point the author wants the no. of files to be reduced and Coalesce is good for it with less or no shuffling @ShubhamJain

Comment: Incase there are more than one partition to be created and we coalesce the df then all the partitions will be reduced to one partition and then distributed but in case of repartition the number of partition will be equal to the number of distinct user_id(partition)

Comment: He wants one file in each partition.. nvm I was just suggesting