# spark repartition to one output file per customer

Tags: data-partitioning

Assume I have a dataframe like:

```
client_id,report_date,date,value_1,value_2
1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2
1,2019-01-01,2019-01-02,3,4
1,2019-01-01,2019-01-03,5,6
2,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2
2,2019-01-01,2019-01-02,3,4
2,2019-01-01,2019-01-03,5,6
```

My desired output structure would be a CSV or JSON with:

```
results/
   client_id=1/
      report_date=2019-01-01
        <<somename>>.csv
   client_id=2/
      report_date=2019-01-01
        <<somename>>.csv
```

To achieve this I use

```
df.repartition(2, "customer_id", "report_date")
  .sortWithinPartitions("date", "value1")
  .write.partitionBy("customer_id", "report_date")
  .csv(...)
```

However, instead of the desired single file per client and report date (partition) I end up with two.

[Spark SQL - Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby) explains why.
However, using a `repartition(1)` would work. But in case the number of `customer_id` is large could run into OOM. Is there still a way to achieve the desired result? The file per client_id is small.

Comment: So, what is the question?  Customer_id is large but then you state is small...

Comment: The data per customer is mall but there are many customers. I want to end up with one single file per customer. My initial strategy was to use spark partitions. However they would only work if repartition 1 is executed. But this will not work as there are too many customers. So is there a different option?

Comment: But in your example that is what I see. What if there are 2 dates for the same customer?

Comment: That is correct. But differentiate `report_date` and `date`. Partitioning os happending per customer_id and 'report_date' i.e. there should be a file per customer_id and report_date.

Comment: But that's what I see happening, I just tried it and got that as you state. So, what to think? On a small sample.

Comment: How much input are you using?

Comment: You do say 1 single file per customer - which is a little confusing.

Comment: On a large cluster not single node installation I get multiple files except using repartition 1

Comment: Prior to aggregation about 1TB

Comment: OK, but I do not really get that as repartition is for DF prior to write via df.write.

Comment: You need to be clear: 1 file per customer or 1 file per customer and reporting date.

Comment: Second case is the desired one

Comment: I ran various tests up to 60M rows of simulated input and I noted I always got your second case. May be the volume I have tried is not enough. But I can see no issue.

Comment: 100M rows, no issue, so leaving it.

Comment: So no issue with repartition 1?

Comment: No, but there is a limit to partition size for Spark. 2GB. Is that what vthe question is about? repartition 1 seems a bad strategy if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Exactly. So is there a way to stil get the desired result without repartition 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187018/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-georg-heiler).

Comment: I ran a large enough dataset on AWS EMR using m4.large with 3 slaves,  a few hundred million simulated rows with repartition(3), and I never got more than one file in the partitioned directory for the combination you mentioned. You say the actual distribution of data is low, so I am a little surprised. I could image that if a file gets too big there will be multiple files but blocks should handle that, but you state - again - that distribution per partitioning keys is low. So, I am not sure. Additional info would need to be provided. I noted some files were ...part_0002.

Comment: On the other hand, you can in this case merge the files as repartition(1) is not a good strategy for throughput.

Comment: So why can I not get the same outcome? the df and writer have same format which should mean 1 fille as ouput. Pls show screenshot. Most curious.

Comment: I will not be able to share a screenshot. For now, explicitly calling `repartition(1)` gives the desired output and I managed to throw money at the problem, i.e. get large enough spark executors. But obviously it will not scale forever like this.

Comment: Indeed and small files. But why can I not get it. May be too small set. But themanuals state this is not a good appoach. Rightly so. Bug?

Comment: I am not sure. But certainly using repartition 1  is not really scalable

Comment: Indeed as I stated

Comment: Any resolution here? I did a whole raft of tests on this topic and could not get your problem.

Comment: For now brute force with large enough executors. This will not scale forever, but it is good enough for now as RAM is rather cheap.

Comment: Curious as may be I am missing  something fundamentally, if you do repartition 1, then a partition may only be max 2GB. How does this work?

Comment: 1) I believe spark 2.4 fixed this issue and 2) I repartition to > 1 but << spar.shuffle.paralellism (and unfortunately need to accept > 1 file per directory / partition

Comment: Cannot find that

Comment: `elimination of the 2GB block size limitation during transfer` from. https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1476 however, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235 turns out to still be open.

Comment: But is that the same thing? I just looked

Comment: you mean my current workaround? or regarding 2.4 and 2GB limitation?

Comment: Appears so, thanks for that I had not seen that.

Comment: My tests on DF writer reveal a few oddities, anyway ...