# Spark : repartitionByRange creating multiple files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing data as Parquet files as below -

```
df.repartitionByRange($"key", rand)
  .write
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 5000)
  .partitionBy("key")
  .parquet("somelocation")
```

I have used a string column(key) for partitioning which is a city as I have more filters based on that.

Even after specifying `maxRecordsPerFile`, multiple small files(tens or hundreds of records) are getting created in 1 partition folder.

Comment: format of your input and how format of your output, please provide some more information?

Comment: @smart_coder I am reading dataframe of parquet files as and storing the same data with partitioning in parquet format

Comment: Could you update the question with the partition column provided?

Comment: I have used maxRecordsPerFile so that i can limit number of records in file. but in 1 partition(say NY)- multiple files are getting created with 50 records or 100 records..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark SQL - Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby)

Comment: not exaclty, my question here is : I am using maxRecordsPerFile then why small files are getting created by repartitionByRange?

Comment: Hmmm.... What language is that? I mean, I think in most languages repartition signature is `repartition(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]`. Having `$"key"` as a first argument doesn't look like a good match, no?

Comment: I think @mazaneicha  comment is highly relevant

Comment: Explanation of repartitionByRange and Repartition along with random key are well explained in below link

https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/on-spark-hive-and-small-files-an-in-depth-look-at-spark-partitioning-strategies-a9a364f908

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the below use case may help to solve your problem,

**Terminologies:**

**1. maxRecordsPerFile** - Limit the max number of records written per file.

**2. repartitionByRange(10, $"id")**

- repartitionByRange(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*)
- which will create  numPartitions by splitting the partitionExprs into partitionExprs/numPartitions equal records splits.
- improve compression when writing data out to disk,
- memory partitioning based
- in order to write data on disk properly, you’ll almost always need to repartition the data in memory first.

**3. partitionedBy("directory you wanted to write")**

- method that specifies if the data should be written to disk in folders. By default, Spark does not write data to disk in nested folders.
- disk level partitioning

**case 1:** `input rows - 1000`, `repartition-10`, maxRecordsPerFile=inputrows/repartitioncount . `1000/10=100`. leads to `10 part-xxxxx` files with equal number of records(`100 records in each file`) within a disk level partition directory(`partition=1`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}
val df=spark.range(1000)
val df1=df.withColumn("partitioncol",lit("1"))

df1.repartitionByRange(10, $"id").write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100).partitionBy("partitioncol").parquet("/FileStore/import-stage/all4")
```

**case 2:** `input rows - 1000`, `repartition-10`, maxRecordsPerFile>inputrows/repartitioncount . `1000`. again leads to `10 part-xxxxx files` with equal number of records(`100 records in each file`) within a disk level partition directory(`partition=1`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}
val df=spark.range(1000)
val df1=df.withColumn("partitioncol",lit("1"))

df1.repartitionByRange(10, $"id").write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000).partitionBy("partitioncol").parquet("/FileStore/import-stage/all4")
```

**case 3:** `input rows - 1000`, `repartition-10`, maxRecordsPerFile<inputrows/repartitioncount, example = `10`. leads to `100 part-xxxxx files` with equal number of records(`10 records in each file`) within a disk level partition directory(`partition=1`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}
val df=spark.range(1000)
val df1=df.withColumn("partitioncol",lit("1"))

df1.repartitionByRange(10, $"id").write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10).partitionBy("partitioncol").parquet("/FileStore/import-stage/all4")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !! before I accept the answer,  Can you please explain me the case where both partitionBy Column and repartitionByRange columns are same.. As In My question its Key column.

Comment: what if I add random as part of partitionExpression in repartitionByRange?