# Spark repartiton, sortWithinParitions and then partitionBy during write is messing with my sort

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition-by

I have scala spark code that writes a dataframe to csv files. The code is shown below

```
dataframe
  .select("path", "id", "top_path")
  .repartition(1, col("top_path"))
  .sortWithinPartitions("path")
  .write
  .partitionBy("top_path")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .csv(outputPath)
```

Even though I am doing a `sortWithinPartitions` on the `path` column, I am still seeing that some of the output isn't sorted as expected. Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed? I have tried `sortWithinPartitions("top_path", "path")` but that still didn't sort by `path` properly when writing. I expect sorting to occur in ascending order by `path`. For example in some cases I am seeing output like

```
path1 1
path1/subpath1 2
path1 3
path1/subpath2 4
```

instead of

```
path1 1
path1 3
path1/subpath1 2
path1/subpath2 4
```

Comment: How do you expect sorting to occur? Pls provide an example.

Comment: @thebluephantom I've added examples. I hope it's good as it is

Comment: OK, but what are you getting; i think i know, but handy to show expected vs actual output

Comment: repartition(1 and column seems to make little sense

Comment: repartition(1, col) means 1 partition per unique col. It makes everything to be written into 1 file for each unique partitoned by col

Comment: I doubt that somehow, but may be I am wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby) (The answer with the highest score, not the accepted one.)

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't @mazaneicha

Comment: @YankiTwizzy Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @krjampani yes. It ended up being a bug with spark itself

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `partitionBy` resets any order that you had before. Try `partitionBy` and then `sortBy`

Comment: sortBy needs to be used together with bucketBy and I don't want to bucket before writing