# Is repartition(num) faster than repartition(num, col)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

Shouldn't `repartition(num_of_partitions_wanted)`, be faster than `repartition(num_of_partitions_wanted, 'id')`? Wondering about other strategies to get even partitions in write outs to parquet in EMR.

My understanding is that repartition, when given a `num_of_partitions`, will try to create even partitions, but is it not reliable enough to create even ones?

We have been passing in `num_of_partitions` and an `id` and it's been creating very even partitions (like all exactly 2 GB or something)

Some notes:

- I've attempted to pass in just the column, but the results are pretty bad because we only pass in a unique ID. (I actually thought it would be good if Spark used a good hash, but I guess there were skewed hash collisions?)

A follow up question is that because our only goal is even partitioning, I saw some stuff in spark config like  `'spark.sql.adaptive.enabled': 'true', 'spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionSize': '500000000'`
and wondering if I just do a `df.write` without a repartition if it'll give me even partitions around 500 MB.

This is only because we want a consistent amount of good sized partitioned across hundreds of tables because right now we just use 10k partitions as a standard and sometimes the partition sizes are in the kilobytes (not ideal with parquet) since our tables can go from megabytes to terabytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between df.repartition and DataFrameWriter partitionBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby)

Comment: @mazaneicha thank you i went over that question, but i'm more concerned about the specific behavior of using repartition(num) without the column, and if we can reliably use it to simply get relatively well distributed partitions and if it is done in less time because it's more random, which may not be the case

Comment: `repartition(n)` ain't random, it uses round-robin to spread rows from the original x into n target partitions. Thats why it also provides pretty much uniform distribution +/- a few rows.

Comment: is there somewhere i can learn more about that? i couldn't find it in just the API reference thank you